# Command to run an application within a specific directory

Tags: cron

I want to be able to type a line of command to do the following two commands that I know:

```
cd ~/rpitwit_commands/
rpitwit
```

This is because I want to automatically run it upon boot in crontab, and it has to run from within that directory. How do you guys suggest I do so? Do note that the actual application file is not in that directory (i'm not sure how this works in debian linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run commands with cron, the $PATH is set to a minimal list, so it's always best to run commands with full path or first set `PATH`.

You can execute multiple commands in one go (works with cron too) like this:

```
cd /home/username/rpitwit_commands && /path/to/command/rpitwit
```

If you need to stay in the original directory after the commands execute, place them between `( )` to run them in a subshell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Does that mean that typing 'reboot (cd /home/pi/rpitwit_commands && rpitwit)' into crontab doesn't make the command run on boot (without logging in)?

Comment: Actually my cron implenation does have some extensions and one of them is @reboot. So if your cron works the same way, you'd need a line like `@reboot cd /home/pi/rpitwit_commands && /path/to/rpitwit` - that isn't the usual way to start a program at boot time but should work.

Comment: @MichaelSuelmann `@reboot` is a perfectly reasonable way of running a command at boot time. It's pretty much the only reliable way to run a command at boot time without admin rights. Also, the `~` will be expanded unless you're running an extremely old antique (which wouldn't have `@reboot` in cron).

Answer (score 2):

You might write it as `cd ~/rpitwit_commands && rpitwit`

Also c[heck out this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369411/bash-script-to-change-directory-and-execute-command-with-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pushd` to change directories to another location and then `popd` to return to where you were.

#### Example

```
$ pwd
/home/saml

$ pushd /tmp/
/tmp ~
$ pwd
/tmp

$ popd
~
$ pwd
/home/saml
```

These command can be chained together using `&&` operators. Go to another directory, `/tmp`, run the command `echo hi`, and return.

```
$ pushd /tmp && echo hi && popd
/tmp ~
hi
```

Confirming we're back:

```
$ pwd
/home/saml
```